# Certificate issue when installing Apache Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Trying to install Airflow on a Windows server, I receive lost of certificate errors. Is there a way to bypass certificates checking while installing?

**For GitPython:**

```
C:\apache-airflow-2.5.1>pip install GitPython
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/gitpython/
```

**For AirFlow:**

```
C:\apache-airflow-2.5.1>python setup.py install
gitpython not found: Cannot compute the git version.
C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
  warnings.warn(
WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/wheel/
```

Is this deprecation warning due to Python 3.11 not being validated by AirFlow?

Is there a simple way of installing AirFlow?

Answer (score 0):

I try the following code to avoid SSL errors and it works:

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

Airflow suggests installation as follows:

```
pip install 'apache-airflow==2.3.3' \
 --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.3.3/constraints-3.9.txt"
```

The package manager `pip` is the only officially supported mechanism of installation using constraint mechanisms by [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/index.html).

> The constraint files are managed by Apache Airflow release managers to
> make sure that you can repeatably install Airflow from PyPI with all
> Providers and required dependencies.

We need to install compatible Airflow and Python versions. Therefore, Airflow dependencies should be working for the Python version. We make sure that happens by adding the constraint argument in the `pip` installation command. This argument has the following format:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-${AIRFLOW_VERSION}/constraints-${PYTHON_VERSION}.txt
```

We have to specify the compatible Airflow and Python versions in the URL.